# Embed video in a playbook app 

Tags: actionscript-3, url, video, embed, blackberry-playbook

How can I embed and play a video from a given url, in a playbook app written in as3? Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using QNX, then follow the examples here: http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/airapi/1.0.0/qnx/media/MediaPlayer.html

I would not recommend using any of the Flex video players, as they will crash on you after 2 videos.